# Tengo problemas para compilar mi proyecto java web

Tags: netbeans, java-8

agregue unas carpetas dentro de mi proyecto java web(8) pero cuando le doy clean and build el esas carpetas o cambios no se compilan, cuando subo el war al servidor y desempaqueto el war esas carpetas no estan alli, es decir no se compilaron, alguno puede ayudarme quizas le paso lo mismo o algo asi

Comment: Hola Duvan, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo que completes el [tour] y leas [ask]. Sin saber la estructura de tu proyecto, dónde has creado las carpetas o las herramientas que usas para la compilación (¿Maven, Gradle?) es complicado saber qué está pasando

Comment: no puedo reproducir tu error. Tal vez quieras agregar mas detalles y un [mcve]